# Using Error report of Google Cloud Platform with ExpressJS

Tags: google-app-engine, express, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

I switched my `ExpressJS` application from `Heroku` to `Google App Engine`.
Everything works ok now.
But I am curious about how to debug my application if some exceptions happen on `GAE`.
On `heroku`, I can do `heroku logs -t` to trace the errors. I can check the variable printed by `console.error(var)` as well.
However, I don't know how to do the same thing on `GAE`.

I have checked logging of Stack Driver, it seems that it only shows some informations of every HTTP request instead of the detailed logs like `heroku`.
I have found that there is error report service of Stack Driver. It may what I want.
Here is the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/app-engine-flexible-environment#send_exception_data) telling us how to setup. But the steps are confusing for me.
Does anyone have the experience to setup the error reporting?
I am finding a more clear steps to setup this.
Thanks a lot and appreciated!

Comment: Stackdriver Error Reporting is still in Beta and we are working hard to improve the setup experience. Alternatively to the setup instruction I provided, we are testing an HTTP API endpoint to send errors, register here if you would like to be an alpha tester: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1JNrDpBQYnpOparS75ab2L1YZHkM3ug3v9j-kWl8g7b0/viewform?c=0&w=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Stackdriver Error Reporting:**

You can use code similar to the one advised for Google Compute Engine: https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/compute-engine#send_exception_data

Here is what worked for me using Express and Winston on App Engine flexible environment:

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: '/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs/my.errors.json' });

var report = function (err, req) {
  var payload = {
    serviceContext: {
      service: 'my service',
    },
    message: err.stack,
    context: {
      httpRequest: {
        url: req.originalUrl,
        method: req.method,
        referrer: req.header('Referer'),
        userAgent: req.header('User-Agent'),
        remoteIp: req.ip,
        responseStatusCode: 500,
      }
    }
  };
  winston.error (payload);
};

// Handle errors
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  report(err, req);
  res.status(500).send(err.response || 'Something broke!');
});
```

**For Stackdriver Logging:**

Indeed, the `request_log` only contains HTTP requests log entries on App Engine flex. Look in the `stdout` log to see the output of your application.

Comment: Thanks, the code makes the tutorial more clear. I have not tested the code yet. But I think that what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read data from the logs, you can try:

```
$ gcloud preview app logs read 
2016-05-30 18:46:29 default[alpha2]  saved to datastore: mountain biking
2016-05-30 18:46:29 default[alpha2]  saved to datastore: adventure
2016-05-30 18:46:29 default[alpha2]  saved to datastore: mountain bike
2016-05-30 18:46:29 default[alpha2]  saved to datastore: cycle sport
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But It seems that the logs it print is the same as the logs of logging service in Stack Driver on Google Cloud.